# Given that$(3x-1)^7=a_7x^7+a_6x^6+a_5x^5+...+a_1x+a_0$, find $a_7+a_6+a_5+a_4+...+a_1+a_0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Given that$$(3x-1)^7=a_7x^7+a_6x^6+a_5x^5+...+a_1x+a_0$$find $$a_7+a_6+a_5+a_4+...+a_1+a_0$$

Is there anyway to do the question without using binomial theorem and expanding the expression on the LHS??

Comment: what happens at $x = 1$ ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HINT:

Set $x=1$ to find $\sum_{r=0}^7 a_r=\cdots$

Answer (score 2):

Consider what happens to $\sum_{i=0}^{7} a_i x^i$ when using $x = 1$. You get $\sum_{i=0}^{7} a_i$. So, calculate $(3x - 1)^7$ when $x = 1$ which is $2^7 = 128$.

Answer (score 0):

Try $x=1$. Then the left hand side is $(3-1)^7$ and the right hand side is $\sum_{i=0}^7 a_i$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x = 1$, then the answer is $2^{7}=128$.